# TLE in a solution with output being matched

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

> Chef has an ore with melting point of *X* degrees. Chef’s kiln has a
> initial temperature of *Y* degrees. The temperature of the kiln
> increases by *i* degrees after the *i*'th minute.
>
> Find the minimum time in minutes after which the ore starts melting.
>
> Note:
>
> We are only concerned about the temperature at the end of each minute
> and not during a minute.
>
> The ore starts melting if the temperature of the kiln becomes greater
> than or equal to the melting point.

For this question here is my code, on which I am facing TLE:

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    x, y = map(int, input().split())
    time = 0
    # x %= pow(10, 9) + 7
    # y %= pow(10, 9) + 7

    if x == y:
        print(0)
    
    else:
        while(x>y):
            time += 1 
            y += time
        
        print(time)
```

Problem link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/MELTGOLD

Comment: *if the temperature of the kiln becomes greater than or equal ...*. I guess that means you should test if `y > x`. Moreover, you get a series with arithmetic progression ...

Comment: @KellyBundy OK. In practice, effectively the loop stops when `y >= x`. The first test `if x == y:` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in `O(X)` time, which is too slow for this problem. They want a solution in constant time.

The observation you ought to make is that:

> `Temperature(i) = Y + 1 + 2 + ... + i`

So,

> `X = Y + i*(i+1)/2`.

> Solve this quadratic for `i` and you get your constant-time solution.

Comment: Theirs is O(sqrt(X-Y)) and it's fast enough to get accepted (just need to use PyPy 3).